# linker always picking system libsasldb.so rather than one provided by LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: c, heroku, ld

I am running in a heroku based environment, so installing packages in system space is not allowed.  To work around this they are installed into `/app/.apt` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is updated to reflect this.

I am trying to use cyrus-sasl2 so install it there and see it is installed, but when I try to use this library I see that it isn't able to pick up gssapiv2 which is also installed in the same location.

Running the code with `LD_DEBUG=all` I see something interesting

```
file=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sasl2/libsasldb.so [0];  dynamically loaded by /app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2 [0]
```

Normally I see libraries do a search, but this is always picking up system and not performing the search.  I was expecting something as follows

```
  1673:
  1673:     file=libsasl2.so.2 [0];  needed by /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sasl/saslwrapper.so [0]
  1673:     find library=libsasl2.so.2 [0]; searching
  1673:      search path=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib:/app/.heroku/python/lib:/app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/app/.apt/usr/lib:tls/x86_64:tls:x86_64:                (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
  1673:       trying file=/app/.heroku/vendor/lib/libsasl2.so.2
  1673:       trying file=/app/.heroku/python/lib/libsasl2.so.2
  1673:       trying file=/app/.apt/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2
```

but I don't see that in the case of `libsasldb.so`.

My question is, why would the linker not search but instead always use the system version?

Answer (score 0):

In the above example, turns out that cyrus-sasl uses a compile time flag to define plugin directories and will load from that path.  I recompiled the project to change the plugin directory to be the heroku location and see the following syscalls

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libcrammd5.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libcrammd5.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libdigestmd5.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libdigestmd5.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libscram.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libscram.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/liblogin.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/liblogin.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libcrammd5.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libldapdb.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libanonymous.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libanonymous.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libplain.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libplain.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libntlm.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libntlm.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libntlm.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libotp.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libldapdb.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libldapdb.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libanonymous.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/liblogin.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libscram.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libotp.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libotp.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libdigestmd5.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
open("/app/.apt/usr/lib/sasl2/libplain.la", O_RDONLY) = 6
```

In short, it controls the linking itself which is why the linker never searches for additional libs.